# the right way to change one under the parent element

Tags: jquery

here is my code,to the object span, I only want to choose the only one element a,when it clicked ,change its color,and others don't need change color.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
    .choose {
        color: red;
    } 
        </style>
        <script src="../jquery-1.10.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
            $('.department > a').click(function() {
                var obja = $('.department >a');
                $(this).toggleClass('choose');
        })
    }) 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <span class="department">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">hello</a>
        <a href="javascript: void(0);">world</a>
        <a href="javascript: void(0);">google</a>
    </span>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: seems fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pVSET/

Comment: So, what is the issue you are facing?? Seems to working fine as in the above fiddle too..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the corrected functionality

```
$(function() {
            $('.department > a').click(function() {
                var obja = $('.department >a');
                $(this).toggleClass('choose').siblings().removeClass('choose');
        })
    })
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ndCty/3/)

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful to you

```
$(function() {
        $('.department > a').click(function() {
            $('.department > .choose').removeClass('choose');
            $(this).toggleClass('choose');
    })
})
```

Check [here in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cppRV/) live in action.

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/ndCty/5/)

```
 $(function () {
     $('.department > a').click(function () {
         var obja = $('.department >a');
         obja.removeClass('choose');
         $(this).addClass('choose');
     })
 })
```